# backspace does not work git bash

Tags: perl, git-bash

The first time I used git bash, backspace was working fine. Then I installed Perl and didn't use git bash for a few days.

When I use backspace in git bash now it doesn't work correctly.

For example, trying to remove the second `s` and everything after it in `ussers`:

[image: Git bash example]

Now when I use the backspace this happens:

[image: git bash example backspace]

Can anyone help?

Comment: A terminal incompatibility. Happened to me a number of times over the years with remote shells (via telnet, ssh, etc). Not sure what the underlying cause, but I think you can work around it using `stty`.

Comment: I think Ctrl-H can be used as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ctrl-H has the same problem as backspace.

Comment: It's probably unrelated to your installation of Perl. What other changes did you make?

Comment: I installed Sublime text 2, silicon labs ide and keil PK51 developer's kit.

Comment: Still can't get it fixed... Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same problem today after switching to mintty with a fresh version of git. In my case, it was an old .bashrc file I'd been carrying around for many years with the line `export TERM=ansi`. After removing that and starting a new bash, everything works again.

More generally, to debug, I was suspicious of all the dot-config stuff in my home directory--so I moved things like .bash_profile, .bashrc, .inputrc, etc. into a temporary directory where they wouldn't be read by bash. Then, I started bash and saw that it worked. I mention it because, if it isn't specifically the TERM issue I had, you might be able to debug using the same technique.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is the same issue.. But I ran into the same after upgrading git

This helped me.. Just enter **TERM=XTERM** in the bash

I got this from an issue log in github..

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQFgT.png)

Comment: TERM=xterm worked for me. It seemed to only work with the correct case though, and needs to be done every time I open it (must be a way of setting it permanently)

Comment: TERM=xterm-256color fixed. My gosh was this the most annoying thing in the world to fix.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case people run into a capitalization issue please type `TERM=xterm-256color` directly into git bash and hit enter. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the menu/title bar of git bash, select options, click on terminal from the options on the left, under the 'type' dropdown, select 'xterm', then apply and save.

Now open a new git bash and it should work :D